# How to hide the output of apt-get install completely?

Tags: apt, package-management

```
 sudo apt-get install wireguard -y >> /dev/null
 sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -qq wireguard < /dev/null > /dev/null
 apt-get install -y -qq wireguard
```

I have tried all the following methods but still, I get following output -

`Extracting templates from packages: 100%`

Comment: Maybe it is a bug that such a text goes to stderr. Which version do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To redirect *all* output, including all error outputs, you need to specify `&>` to redirect. This redirects both `stdout` and `stderr`. For your example, you would do so like this:

```
sudo apt-get install wireguard -y &> /dev/null
```

Do note, however, that it is usually not recommended to do this on operations such as installing packages, since it will be harder to debug if something goes wrong (and you won't know if something goes wrong or not). Therefore if you want to hide all output, I would recommend redirecting to a regular file instead, for example `&> ~/apt-log.txt`. Do it at your own risk :)